# Big-O for-loop runtime analysis

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, runtime, big-o

```
 int n = 500;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum++;
```

My guess is this is simply a O(N^2), but the j < i is giving me doubts.

```
int n = 500;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
            sum++;
```

Seems like an O(N^3)

```
  int n = 500;
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < i*i; j++)
            if( j % i == 0 )
               for( k = 0; k < j; k++ )
                  sum++
```

O(N^5)?

So for each loop j has a different value. If it was j < n*n, it would've been more straight forward, but this one is a tricky one, so please help. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that the O notation is just scaling behavior. Just ask yourself, if the size of input change, how do the number of operations scale accordingly - and you have it.

Comment: I've voted to close this question. There's hundreds of similar questions already and they're all too narrow to be useful in general. The question I've said is a duplicate provides tools to allow people to compute big-O themselves.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case `sum++` executes `0 + 1 + ... + n-1` times. If you apply [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) formula, you'll get `n (n-1) / 2`, which is `O(n^2)`.

In the second case we'll have `0 + 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + (n-1)^2`, which is sum of squares of first `n-1` numbers, and there's [a formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16) for it: `(n-1) n (2n-1)`

The last one is interesting. You can see, actually, that the most nested `for` loop is called only when `j` is a multiplicand of `i`, so you can rewrite the program as follows:

```
int n = 500;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   for(int m = 0; m < i; m++) {
       int j = m * i;
       for( k = 0; k < j; k++)
             sum++
   }
}
```

It's easier to work with math notation:

[image: Derivation]

The formula is derived from the code by analysis: we can see that `sum++` gets called `j` times in the innermost loop, which is called `i` times, which is called `n` times. In the end, the problem boils down to a sum of cubes of first `n` numbers plus lower-order terms (which do not affect the asymptotics)

One final note: it looks obvious, but I'd like to show that in general sum of first `N` natural numbers in `d`th power is `Ω(N^(d+1))` (see Wikipedia for [Big-Omega notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Knuth_definition)), that is it grows no slower than that function. You can apply the same reasoning to prove that a stronger condition is satisfied, namely, it belongs to `Θ(N^(d+1))`, which combines both `Ω` and `O`.

[image: Derivation]

Comment: Hi. Appreciate your lengthy answer, but I couldn't quite understand what you were trying to say exactly for the very last problem. I did not see you conclude with an answer for it so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @btrballin, you mean very last problem of yours, or my derivation of sum of `d`th powers? The conclusion for the first one is that the running time is `O(n^4)`, rather than `O(n^5)`, and the final note is a "proof" that if you have a loop `for k in [1..n]` which body has `O(k^d)` running time, then the loop will run in `O(n^(d+1))`. The reason I included this derivation is that in the first 3 examples I used the fact that sum of natural numbers, sum of squares, sum of cubes — all have a closed formula of higher order. The last paragraph generalizes these results.

Answer (score 1):

You are right for all but the last one, which has a tighter bound of `O(n^4)`: note that the last `for` loop is only executed if `j` is a multiple of `i`. There are `x / i` multiples of `i` lower than or equal to `x`, and `i * i / i = i`. So the last loop is only executed for `i` values out of the `i * i`.

Note that big-oh gives an upper bound, so `i*i` vs `n*n` makes little difference. Strictly speaking, saying they are all `O(n^2015)` is also correct (because that is a valid upper bound), but it's hardly helpful, so in practice a tight bound is usually used.

Answer (score 0):

IVlad already gave the correct answer.

I think what confuses you is the "Big Oh" definition.

- N^2 has O(N^2)
- 1/2N^2 has O(N^2)
- 1/2N^2 + c*N + b also has
  O(N^2) - by given c and b are constants independent from N

Check Big Oh definition from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)